# Help with sorting content documents by custom field on its LinkedEntity

Tags: soql, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, conga-composer

This SOQL statement works, but I'm trying to sort the Content Documents by a field e.g. Sort_Order__c on Invoice__c.

```
SELECT ContentDocument.id,LinkedEntity.Name,LinkedEntityId
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (
     SELECT Id
     FROM Invoice__c
     WHERE Funding_Order__c = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)
```

We need to pull together a funding order where each invoice has one or more related files and they need to be in a certain sort order.

Is this possible in a single SOQL query? I was hoping to use the query in Conga Composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making a trigger (or a flow if possible) that inserts a special join record when contentdocumentlink is created that has a relationship to the sobject and the contentdocumentlink record.

This way you have all the related records available via parent relationships, and your sort will work.

```
SELECT Parent_CDL__c, Parent_Entity__c, Parent_Entity__r.Name 
FROM CDL_Record_Join__c
WHERE Parent_Entity__c IN (SELECT Id FROM Invoice__c WHERE Funding_Order__c = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
ORDER BY Parent_Entity__r.Sort_Order__c
```

(All above objects and relationships are hypothetical of course)

Actual solution as added by OP: (unable to use actual relationship queries, but that didn't matter in this case)

> Solution is a custom junction object that can store info that wasn't
> possible on using the standard Salesforce ContentDocumentLink object.
> The custom junction object that works has a text field that stores the
> ContentDocument record Id, and Funding_Draw__c (Master-Detail),
> Invoice_Item__c (Master-Detail) fields. This allows me to create a
> Conga query that sorts correctly as follows:

```
SELECT ContentDocument_Id__c 
FROM Invoice_Item_Content_Doc_Link__c 
WHERE Funding_Draw__c = '{pv0}' ORDER BY Invoice_Item__r.Draw_Sort_Order__c
```

### Alternative Approach

How about still using a Trigger/Flow and putting the Sort_Order__c in the `ContentDocument.Description` field.

Then you can sort like this:

```
SELECT ContentDocument.Id,LinkedEntity.Name,LinkedEntityId
FROM ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (
     SELECT Id
     FROM Invoice__c
     WHERE Funding_Order__c = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)
ORDER BY ContentDocument.Description ASC
```

Comment: That's a brilliant idea.  I'll give it a try!

Comment: Alas, I tried creating a new junction object, but it's not possible to select the CDL object as either a master or lookup.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe just use the `ContentDocument` itself? I suppose you are making your own link anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work either since each ContentDocument can have many sort orders.  I do like your original idea, though and still think it will work.  I realized I don't need an actual relationship field to the ContentDocumentLink.  I can just use a text field to the Id.  I'll give that a try and report back.

Comment: Caspar-I want to thank you for your original solution.  This helped me figure out that I needed a new custom junction object that provided the ability to store additional information that we couldn

Comment: Glad it helped, even if only derivatively.

Comment: Caspar THANK YOU! Solution is a custom junction object that can store info that wasn't possible on using the standard Salesforce ContentDocumentLink object.  The custom junction object that works has a text field that stores the ContentDocument record Id, and Funding_Draw__c (Master-Detail), Invoice_Item__c (Master-Detail) fields.  This allows me to create a Conga query that sorts correctly as follows. 

SELECT ContentDocument_Id__c FROM Invoice_Item_Content_Doc_Link__c WHERE Funding_Draw__c = '{pv0}' ORDER BY Invoice_Item__r.Draw_Sort_Order__c

Comment: Awesome! I'll add that to the answer so it's in a more secure format than a chat.